# Edit post meta direct from post.php?

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, metabox, post-meta

Does anyone know of an easy way to be able to edit ALL of a single post's meta at once ie on the `post.php`  `&action=edit` page?

As some of the meta has been put in there with the `update_post_meta()` and isn't consistent between posts it would be really helpful to have a way of just editing ANY meta value from the post's edit page?

Have been scouring around for anything, code / plugins and can't see it mentioned much but thought it must be a common enough problem?

I've attached an image of my imagined solution from a meta inspector edited through the browser inspector just in case it isn't clear what I'm asking

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: So does every post have the same set of meta keys & values? If so I would just do an update query in phpMyAdmin or something similar..

Comment: Unfortunately there are different keys and values for most of the pages depending on what the `update_post_meta` is storing. Otherwise I could simply register another meta box and use that to edit each. - Also I should mention I only want to change one individual post at a time.

Comment: Can you provide any criteria regarding which fields you are trying to edit/change? I assume you don't want `check_in`, `event`, `event_date`, and `member` to be completely identical, yes? Please describe what you are trying to do a bit more clearly.

Comment: I'd like to be able to edit EVERY piece of meta, at my leisure on an individual post basis. Each post has different Keys and data that would be v labour intensive to register and create meta boxes for each one. The image was just used as an example.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the issue. you'd only need a single meta box that outputs all the meta via `get_post_custom`.

Comment: Hi Milo, how do you mean? Surely I would have to register each meta key to create an editable box? Maybe this is the bit I need some help with then...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So awkwardly realised I'd been going about this whole thing in a stupid roundabout way and in fact Milo above in the comments is completely right, and proves that the codex still has secrets for everyone, or maybe just me.

The eureka (or durr-eka) moment came after reading [this post here](http://wptheming.com/2010/08/custom-metabox-for-post-type/) about setting up and editing the content of the metaboxes.

Instead of calling the individual meta to be edited using `get_post_meta` I used the `get_post_custom()` and simply cycled through every post meta entry using a `foreach` loop and a simple `isset` form for each generated.

Apologies for the obvious question but thought I'd answer it myself rather than delete it in case anyone else out there is doing it wrong too.